# how to use jbuilder with yajl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I am using jbuilder to render JSON in Rails. However, I would like to use Faster JSON backend, as stated in jbuilder's GitHub. How can I use it? Is it just config in Application.rb?

```
require 'multi_json'
MultiJson.use :yawl
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To integrate `yajil-ruby` you have to follow the bellow steps

> Note : These steps are tested in rails 4.2.3

1) Add `gem 'yajl-ruby', require: 'yajl'` to Gemfile

2) rub `bundle install`

3) now check default json renderer is changed to yajl by enter this command in rails console `MultiJson.engine` then you should see the below result

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
1.8.7 :001 > MultiJson.engine
 => MultiJson::Adapters::Yajl < MultiJson::Adapter
```

Thats it , now your default renderer is yajl